# mysql join 3 tables related in pairs

Tags: php, mysql, join

**► Context** : I work in a museum (for real), people come everyday, they buy tickets for themselves (humans) and sometimes they also buy tickets for drinks and foods (objects). There are events, tickets have the **same names** per event but the prices are different.

**► The problem** : I have to create a report with 2 results : **total sales** (visitors + food + drinks) and **how many people came** (visitors only) for a specific event. Next is an image of the 3 tables in the database, how they relate and some sample data :

- Table TICKETS relates to SALES_MAIN through **EVENT_ID** column.
- Table SALES_MAIN relates to SALES_DETAIL through **ID**→**MAIN_ID** columns.
- Table SALES_DETAIL have a column **TICKET_NAME** but it's not unique in table TICKETS.

[image]

**► The question** : How to get both results, **total sales and human count**, for event **555** in one "select" ? I tried next 2 "select" but when I combine them with another INNER JOIN I get cartesian results :

Get detail sales for event **555** :

```
SELECT sales_detail.* FROM sales_main
INNER JOIN sales_detail ON sales_detail.main_id = sales_main.id
WHERE sales_main.event_id = '555'
```

Get tickets for event **555** :

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE tickets.event_id = '555'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN sd.ticket_name IN ('adult', 'child') THEN sd.quantity 
           ELSE 0 END) AS total_visitors,
  SUM(sd.quantity * t.price)  AS total_sales
FROM sales_main sm
JOIN sales_detail sd
  ON sd.main_id = sm.id
JOIN ticket t
  ON t.event_id = sm.event_id
 AND t.ticket_name = sd.ticket_name
WHERE sm.event_id = '555';
```

Conditional aggregation could also be based on type:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN t.ticket_type ='human' THEN sd.quantity ELSE 0 END)
```